# Making DataGridView rows a certain color based on a column value

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I am using vb.net and I have data coming into my DGV and I have a column labeled deployed if it's a '1', I want to have all the rows with '1' in the deployed column RED and if it's a '0', I want all the rows to be GREEN. This is my method I have, right now the column is the 10th column but it doesn't like the = operator. Even when I use quotes on the 1 with equals compare operator for strings. Should be an integer but I was trying every way I could to see why it's not working.

```
Private Sub LaptopGrid_CellFormatting(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles LaptopGrid.CellFormatting
    For i As Integer = 0 To LaptopGrid.Rows.Count - 1
        If LaptopGrid.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value = 1 Then
            LaptopGrid.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

First, you are handling the `CellFormatting` event but you are iterating every row to set the backcolor.  That event is meant for you to do something to a *single, specific cell*, the one in question is indicated in the event args: `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex`.  Using a loop, you are acting on many more rows than needed and doing so over and over.

Second, VB has data types.  `Int32` is one type, `String` is another, and `Object` is yet another.  You need to convert one type to the other type before you compare. `LaptopGrid.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value` returns `Object` (since a cell can literally hold anything), so to compare to `1` you need to convert it to integer.

Finally, you may not want the `CellFormatting` event for this.  If the cell in question is not on screen, the event wont fire (perhaps the user resized the columns). `RowPrePaint` on the other hand will fire when the row scrolls into view.

```
Private Sub dgv1_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, 
                   e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles dgv1.RowPrePaint

    ' dont do the NewRow
    If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return

    ' convert to int32, then compare
    ' act on just this row - e.RowIndex
    If Convert.ToInt32(dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value) > 3 Then
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon
    Else
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.MistyRose
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

If the user can edit that cell value, you will want to update the back color accordingly.