# Creating a Datagridview that updates on CellClick

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm a novice when it comes to coding in vb.net and I am not confident with `DataGridView` so I need a starting point/solution to a current project.

I'm building an application where my DGV connects to my SQL server, reads the database table and acts as a progress chart to record which step each job is at.

My plan is tell the app to turn every cell that contains "Y" orange. 
I want to insert a `CellClick` event so that when a cell is clicked it inputs a "Y" into the SQL server table, thus turning it Orange. Then when the last column of the row is clicked, for it to turn the whole row green to indicate the job is complete.

I've included my initial design idea to help with visualising how the final outcome should look. I haven't included any code because it currently doesn't work and I don't think it would help.

Desired finished table:

[image]

Comment: I might do it differently.  Those look like sequential steps, so a simple integer value could be used.  A Status of 3 would mean to color cells {0,1,2} for that row which is easily done in the RowPrePaint event or maybe CellFormatting.  I'd also use a button column for the update which more clearly conveys what to do.  Not sure what the data for those columns is though

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Plutonix do you know where there might be an example of `RowPrePaint`? I've not seen that event before so it would be useful to me. Thanks.

Comment: All the events are available from the dropdown selector in the code window.  MSDN has gobs of examples, of course.  An example here: [Making displayed rows a certain color in datagridview based on the entry of one column](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39732068/1070452)

Comment: This is a good example, I should be able to work mine of this example. Thanks!