# changing cell backcolor of Datagridview with events

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, colors, cell

what i gonna show u now is a part from bigger program but in this part i have problem.
so in image below there is 3 controls combobox, button and datagridview

[enter image description here][1]

when i click the button the text in the combobox added to the datagridview table and if combobox was empty when i click the button the backcolor of datagridview cell in the new row stay white but the combobox have text in it when the button clicked the backcolor of datagridview cell in the new row become red i set this up with rowadded event...
 this is the code

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded
    Dim ccc As Integer

    For ccc = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(ccc).Cells(1).Value.ToString <> "" Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(ccc).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

more than that in handeled  cellMousedoubleclick event and make it change the current cell backcolor to green...
 this is the code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDoubleClick
    DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Green
End Sub
```

intel now every thing is ok, the problem starts when add new row after that,this action make every thing back like it was before

this is the problems images http://www.file-upload.cc/gd4je2hpw6go

as you can see the green color is disappear after adding the 333 row
so please any one can help me to preserve the changings after adding new row ??

Comment: use the RowPrepaint or CellFormatting event to set the color(s)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39732962/1070452

Comment: Hi Plutonix .... i used that and i tried the cell painting to  but i faced another problem which is that i can't change the red color after that !!!!

Comment: *use the **RowPrepaint** or **CellFormatting** event*.  In the code you have, you set it once only.  CellFormatting will re-fire when values change.  Use an `Else` statement to change it back from red or whatever.

Comment: ok i'll give it another try thnx :-)

Comment: not working :-(   ..... every thing changed to green exapte the red cells