# Eliminating For-Loop in CellFormatting sub

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop, datagridview

I have a `CellFormatting` sub that won't work correctly with the code I've written because it includes a loop (it interferes with the UI). Getting rid of the loop fixes the problem but I can't workout how to eliminate it while keeping the equation i have. This was the code **WITH** the loop

```
    For k = 8 To 52 Step 2
        If row.Cells(k).Value Is DBNull.Value Or row.Cells(k).Value Is Nothing Then Continue For                    

        Dim firstDate As Date = DirectCast(row.Cells(k).Value, Date)                                                
        Dim N As Date = Now                                                                                         
        Dim diff As TimeSpan = N - firstDate                                                                        

        If diff.Days > 14 AndAlso row.Cells(k + 1).Value = 0 Then                                                   
            row.Cells(k - 1).Value = 6                                                                              
        ElseIf diff.Days > 14 AndAlso row.Cells(k + 1).Value <> 0 Then                                              
            row.Cells(k - 1).Value = row.Cells(k - 3).Value                                                         
        End If
    Next k
```

And this is the code **WITHOUT** the loop I've tried to replace it with. I've replaced `k` for `e.columnIndex` which fixes the UI problems, but the code won't actually do anything on my `DataGridView`

```
    If row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value Is DBNull.Value Or row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value Is Nothing Then                     
        If e.ColumnIndex >= 8 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex <= 52 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Dim firstDate As Date = DirectCast(row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value, Date)                                                
            Dim N As Date = Now                                                                                         
            Dim diff As TimeSpan = N - firstDate                                                                        

            If diff.Days > 14 AndAlso row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 0 Then                                                   
                row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex - 1).Value = 6                                                                              
            ElseIf diff.Days > 14 AndAlso row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value <> 0 Then                                             
                row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex - 1).Value = row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex - 3).Value                                                        
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

How can I write the above code block (keeping out the loop) and still make it work the same as the first code block in this question?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You dont loop in that event.  The event args tell you which cell to act on.  See [Making DataGridView rows a certain color based on a column value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39732962)

Comment: @Plutonix that's why I've taken the loop out and substituted `k` for `e.columnindex` in the second code block. If the code will only work with a loop what event should it go in?

Comment: `e.ColumnIndex Mod 2 = 8` is wrong. there can never be true. `e.ColumnIndex Mod 2 = 0` is correct

Comment: @KeithMifsud Hi, I did initially try `e.ColumnIndex Mod 2 = 0` but that didn't work so I tried changing mod. still didn't work but i forgot to change it back, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Rather than that cryptic column selection code, you could see if the name is in an array of target names or indicies. something like `AndAlso TgtCols.Contains(e.columnIndex) Then...`

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for your reply. Having at look at your answer to the other question linked it does look like the `CellFormatting` sub is meant to handle one cell at a time so it's not executing my code. I'm not sure `AndAlso TgtCols.Contains(e.columnIndex) Then...` would work because there's nothing to target except even columns between 8 and 52

Comment: The even columns between 8 and 52 **do** have an index and a name, so it would work

Comment: @Plutonix Ah fair enough. I've not worked with arrays before so I'm just studying them now. Just out of interest all the examples I've seen still use a for-loop for the arrays, would this still not disrupt the `CellFormatting` sub?